# Have PST Sub-Folders Show In Favorites

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, pst

I created a PST folder called Co-Workers and the main folder is called Co-Workers where within this folder I have roughly 20 sub-folders with the names of each of my co-workers.

I want to be able to access the Co-Workers folder from my "Favorites" in Outlook 2016, but when I right click the folder and select Add to Favorites, it only adds the main folder (which is empty) it does not add the sub-folders.

I do not want to add all 20 sub-folders to my favorites, as that would become quite cumbersome and would not give me the ability to "retract" the folder when I do not need to see the folders.

Is there a way to move the main folder as well as the sub-folders to be accessible from within my favorites from my pst file, so that I can expand and retract the Co-Workers main folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no way. Outlook favorites folders list works per-folder. You can't have a folder tree there.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was hoping there would be a way to do it.